# 2D Array check surroundings

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D array which acts as a game board and the user can make moves into certain cells etc and each user has a specific id e.g. player 1 replaces the cells in the array with their playerId = 1.

I am trying to create a method to find out when the user's `playerId` gets stuck. They get stuck when they are surrounded by another a value which is not 0.

For example, if player 1 is in the cell 2,5 then P(which represents a 0) is the possible moves they can make. However, if the player was surrounded by other values then they should not be able to make a move (return false).

```
xxxPPPxxxx
xxxP1Pxxxx
xxxPPPxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
```

Method:

```
public boolean checkBlocked(int[][] array,List<Coordinates> track,int playerId)
{
    boolean blocked = false;
    int trueCount = 0;
    for (Coordinates cells: track)
    {
        int x = cells.getX();
        int y = cells.getY();
        if(array[x-1][y-1] == 0 ) trueCount++; //topleft
        if(array[x-1][y] == 0) trueCount++; //top
        if(array[x-1][y+1] == 0) trueCount++;//topright
        if(array[x][y+1] == 0) trueCount++;//right
        if(array[x][y-1] == 0) trueCount++;//left
        if(array[x+1][y-1] == 0) trueCount++;//bottomleft
        if(array[x+1][y] == 0) trueCount++;//bottom
        if(array[x+1][y+1] == 0) trueCount++; //bottomright
    }

    if (trueCount == 0)
    {
        blocked = true;
    }
    return blocked;
}
```

I tried to do this method, but then this doesn't work because the 2D array is 6x10 and then if the cell is 1,1 or 6,1 then it gives an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Is there an easier way that I can do this check or a way around the exception?

Comment: well you can check for the length of the array before accessing the position

Comment: Just for the record: A) the name "array" is not telling anything to the reader B) that param playerId isn't use in that method, so dont put it into the signature. Instead of having a separate "trueCount" ... simply return false for all places that say trueCount++, and return true (once, in the end of your method).

Comment: @GhostCat will change that up, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Three solutions

- Make the array larger in all directions (and make walls that are invisible/impenetrable) -- This has the highest performance and is my favorite trick for image processing.
- Make a method like `getBoardSquare` that does the bounds checking for you and returns a special value (or 'wall' value) for out-of-bound coordinates -- this has the best 'code readability'
- Do manual extensive bounds checking wherever you access the array -- not recommended

Comment: ok thanks , I'll try making the array larger.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that surround cells are in the board. To do so you could add additional checks to all of the `if`. E.g.:

```
if(x > 0 && y > 0 && array[x-1][y-1] == 0) trueCount++;
if(x > 0 && array[x-1][y] == 0) trueCount++;
if(x > 0 && y < array[x-1].length - 1 && array[x-1][y+1] == 0) trueCount++;
```

I think, it is better to create separate method with internal check:

```
private static int get(int[][] array, int row, int col) {
    return row < 0 || row >= arr.length || col < 0 || col >= array[row].length ? 0 : array[row][col];
}
```

and us it in your `if`:

```
if(get(array, x-1, y-1) == 0) trueCount++;
if(get(array, x-1, y) == 0) trueCount++;
if(get(array, x-1, y+1) == 0) trueCount++;
```

Finally, I think it's better to encapsulate `Board` logic into separate class:

```
public class Board {

    private final int[][] board;

    public Board(int row, int col) {
        board = new int[row][col];
    }

    public boolean isBlocked(int row, int col) {
        if (cell(row - 1, col - 1) == 0 || cell(row - 1, col) == 0 || cell(row - 1, col + 1) == 0)
            return false;
        if (cell(row, col + 1) == 0 || cell(row, col - 1) == 0)
            return false;
        if (cell(row + 1, col - 1) == 0 || cell(row + 1, col) == 0 || cell(row + 1, col + 1) == 0)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    private int cell(int row, int col) {
        return row < 0 || row >= board.length || col < 0 || col >= board[row].length ? 0 : board[row][col];
    }

}
```

**P.S.**

> Check your `x` and `y`. `x` - column and `y` - row, so it means
>   `arr[y][x]` but not `arr[x][y]`!

Comment: See updated version